# Using C# to sort a column in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to sort a worksheet by the first column in excel using `INTEROP`.

I just want a simple sort of the entire range by the first column. I am doing the following:

```
valueRange.Sort(valueRange.Columns[7, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, valueRange.Columns[7, Type.Missing],
                Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, 
                Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, 
                Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, 
                Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

But getting errors. I am unable to find proper documentation on how to do this sorting.

Could someone please give me a working example of a simple sort of a specified range by a specific column?

as per documentation I tried to do this:

```
valueRange.Sort(valueRange.Columns[7, Type.Missing],
                        Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                        Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
                        Excel.XlSortMethod.xlStroke,
                        Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
                        Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
                        Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

However right now I am getting the errors:

> {"The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."}

Comment: you can record macro with macro-recorder in excel and convert vba to c#

Comment: See [This MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.sort.aspx#Y0)

Comment: What error are you getting? One of the hassles of Interop, as you can probably tell, is having to pass seemingly endless parameters to the various functions; there's lots of room for error.

Comment: @andrew not sure how to convert vba to c#

Comment: What is your big-picture goal?  If you just want to work with the data from .NET, it might be easier to load it into DataTable and work with it there instead of through Excel Interop.

Comment: @mellamokb no i def need the interop, i am making changes to an excelfile that has formatting and a lot of fancy stuff, and i need to keep it

Comment: @chrisneilsen i followed the documenhtation you gave me please check updated question

Comment: @PatrickPitre i am gettign this errror: {"The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to sort a range by a single column in that range, you can do something like the following (if you are using VS 2010 and above with the "dynamic" keyword):

```
dynamic allDataRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
allDataRange.Sort(allDataRange.Columns[7], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending);
```

In my example, I had a spreadsheet with 10 or so columns, and I wanted to sort the entire spreadsheet by the 7th column, in descending order.

I was helped by the above answer, but when I tried Code4Life's snippet:

```
dynamic valueRange = GetTheRange();
valueRange.Columns.get_Item(1)).Sort(valueRange.Columns[1]);
```

it only sorted the first column of the range.  The OP asked for sorting an entire range by one column, not sorting one column in a range.  So after a little trial and error I got my above simplified code.

Comment: Thank you very useful for when working with them pesky COM calls.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
((Excel.Range)valueRange.Columns.get_Item(1, Type.Missing))
    .Sort(valueRange.Columns[1, Type.Missing],
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing,
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin,   
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

Basically, do your `Sort` from the `Column`, not the base range.

Also, I would strongly recommend using Visual Studio 2010 if you can. The above code gets simplified down to this in VS 2010:

```
dynamic valueRange = GetTheRange();
valueRange.Columns.get_Item(1)).Sort(valueRange.Columns[1]);
```

**EDIT**:
If you need to sort across multiple columns, Excel allows you to sort on up to **three** columns. Here's how you would do it:

```
valueRange.Sort(valueRange.Columns[1, Type.Missing], // the first sort key
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, 
    valueRange.Columns[2, Type.Missing], // second sort key
    Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, 
    valueRange.Columns[3, Type.Missing], // third sort key
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, 
    Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin,   
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, 
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

**EDIT2**:
Loading values into a 2D array:

```
var myArray = (object[,])valueRange.Value2;
```

Loading the array back into the range:

```
var arrayCount = myArray.GetLength(0);
var columnCount = GetTheColumnCountHere();
valueRange = valueRange.get_Resize(arrayCount, columnCount);
valueRange.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, myArray);
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!!! unfortunately it ONLY sorted the first column and not the rest of the data

Comment: the last column is called CO, around 89

Comment: If you need to sort on more than 3 columns, I suggest extracting the worksheet data out into a 2-dimensional array (`var ar = (object[,]range.value2`), then sort the array, and finally save the array into the worksheet.

Comment: im sorry can you please show me what that woudl look like thank you again