# C# Reorder columns of Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

I have an Excel worksheet with some data. I also have a List of the column headers of the worksheet. The headers in the list are in a different order than the headers in the worksheet, and I need to reorder the Excel worksheet's columns to be the same order as the list.

```
List<string> dataset1Variables = new List<string>() { "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4" };
```

The headers of my Excel sheet may look like this:

### Variable 3 | Variable 1 | Variable 4 | Variable 2

I have come across this code to shift columns but this is only for moving 1 column to a specific location. The list might be completely mixed up so I would need to shift many columns.

```
Excel.Range copyRange = xlWs.Range["C:C"];
Excel.Range insertRange = xlWs.Range["A:A"];
insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, 
copyRange.Cut());
```

What would be the best approach for doing this? Preferably using Interop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty row right above your worksheet with data, you can add matching formula right above headers. In below assuming your list is on Sheet2 range B2:B5 and your data headers start on Sheet1 range A2:D2

```
Excel.Workbook myBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"path\excel.xlsx");
Excel.Worksheet ws = myBook.Worksheets[1];

// You can use all dynamic ranges instead
// Excel.Range xlRng = ws.Range[ws.Cells[yourRow, firsColumn], ws.Cells[yourRow, lastColumn]];
Excel.Range xlRng = ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[1, 4]]; // ws.Range["A1:D1"];
xlRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(R[-1]C,Sheet2!R2C2:$R5C2,0)";
// Below is how you can get full address for your list if it's in different workbook and replace Sheet2!R2C2:$R5C2 with rangeFullAddress
// string rangeFullAddress = xlRng.Address[true,true,Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1,true];
xlRng.Calculate();
xlRng.Value = xlRng.Value;
```

After this you can just sort your data using Excel Sort by 1st row. After sorting your 1st row it would look like this: 1, 2, 3, 4. Then clear data on 1st row `ws.Range["A1:D1"].Clear();`.

Your sort key would be `Key1: ws.Range["A1:D1"]`, here is c# sort example [using c# to sort a column in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982318/using-c-sharp-to-sort-a-column-in-excel) only change Excel.XlSortOrientation and adjust for your range.

There are other ways to sort but this way you'll keep individual formats, comments of each cell within your data

I missed 1 important detail - that your list is not in Excel sheet, but you can add it to Excel, perhaps in temporary workbook or right on the same sheet:

```
        object [,] columnHeaders = new object[3,0]; // or object[0,3]; if you'd like to add into 1 row
        columnHeaders[0, 0] = "Variable1";
        columnHeaders[1, 0] = "Variable2";
        columnHeaders[2, 0] = "Variable3";
        columnHeaders[3, 0] = "Variable4";
        xlRng.FormulaR1C1 = columnHeaders; // xlRng would be in the above Sheet2!R2C2:$R5C2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I probably should have mentioned that the number of columns in the Excel sheet is never fixed. i.e I will be working with many different excel files and each file may have different number of columns.

Comment: Then you can make it dynamic Excel.Range xlRng = ws.Range[ws.Cells[yourRow, firsColumn], ws.Cells[yourRow, lastColumn]]; I have adjusted the code. Everything can be made dynamic in the above code. The formula would work in any case for as long as you make your list range the same way dynamic.

Comment: I missed 1 important detail that your list is not in Excel and made adjustment at the end of my answer

Comment: Richard thanks so much for your solution. In the end I went with a different one which seems to do the job without needing to alter the Excel files which is preferable. Basically what I did was create a second list with the column order of the Excel file. So I compare the two lists and using looping manage to move the columns to the correct index location with the Range.Insert command.