# C#: Excel Sort() row by date string can't work properly

Tags: c#, excel

I have original data here

[image]

And I want to sort it by date.

I use this:[C# sort excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982318/using-c-sharp-to-sort-a-column-in-excel)

I write just like this

```
 allDataRange = sheet.get_Range("A1", "E7");
            allDataRange.Sort(allDataRange.Rows[1], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending);
```

Then I got

[image]
I have tried `allDataRange.Rows[3]`,but I got the same result.
And then I try the `allDataRange.Rows[100]`,the result is same.It seems it can not be sort by row?

Last attach the result of sorted by Columun3

[image]

It seems that the function sort by column works good.

I'm really puzzled on it.Why does it work so mysteriously?

=======update======

Someone has answered this question but now remove it.Thank you here.

I get the idea and try`allDataRange.Sort(allDataRange.Rows[1], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows,Excel.XlSortMethod.xlStroke,Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);`
but it prompts a syntax bug.

I have checked document from [How to: Programmatically Sort Data in Worksheets](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ff4f361-d7f3-4d03-9414-8c9c56b74ddb/how-to-sort-column-data-of-excel-usinf-c?forum=csharpgeneral)and [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.sort.aspx),but I can't find the error.

**I Find It.**

[image]