# Sort a worksheet by a column using Interop

Tags: excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I've found various related code on the Internet but nothing seems to work. Maybe someone can point out my error:

```
// Get a Range of the data to sort
// (I also tried to use _worksheet.UsedRange, but it fails - why?)
var dataToSort = _worksheet.Range["A2", $"Z{lastLine}"];

// Sort range
dataToSort.Sort(_worksheet.Range["A2"]);
```

Funny enough it resorts the columns instead of the rows...

Actually I want to write something like this:

```
_worksheet.Sort(columnIndex: 1);
```

But I can't find a suitable overload.

My Sheet looks like this:

```
1 |      |       |
2 | Z    | Data2 |
3 | A    | Data1 |
```

I want it to look like this afterwards:

```
1 |      |       |
2 | A    | Data1 |
3 | Z    | Data2 |
```

(Using Excel 2019 and Excel Interop 15 for an xlsx file)

Comment: Note that the answer to the "duplicate" question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888409/1400869 does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, for whatever reason the [sort orientation default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsortorientation) is `xlSortRows`. I had to switch to `xlSortColumns` and now it works with this simple oneliner:

```
_worksheet.UsedRange.Sort(_worksheet.Columns[1], Orientation: XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns);
```